# Is it possible to create the jdl file from user input and then generate classes from it? I would be very happy if you could give an example

Tags: spring, jhipster, jdl

I'm new to jhipster. Is it possible to create the jdl file from user input and then generate classes from it? I would be very happy if you could give an example. I want to create a web app, basically main idea is creating a configuration with paramaters(user input) and generate its entity classes.

Pls give me a solution for creating jdl file from user input and then generate classes from it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. But you could use [JDL Studio](https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/) or the [IntelliJ JHipster JDL Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19697-jhipster-jdl) to create your JDL.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of having JDL file and [JDL studio](https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/) is to ensure that users don't have to define their complex entities via the command line and have an easier visual tool to do the same.
If you use user input to generate a JDL file and then again use that to generate classes it will make things more complex, instead you can simply model your entities in the JDL studio.

But you can create a custom [blueprint](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/) to achieve what you need (creating JDL file from user input) via extending the "prompt" lifecycle method and creating a JDL file out of that. Later in the next step you can use the generated JDL file to create your entity classes.
Though I feel this is an anti-pattern and should not be used.